# How do I send details from the form to a rest API in ember.js?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, frontend

I'm relatively new to ember and I have been trying to send a POST request to REST API. Can someone explain how POST request is done in ember?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what parts of Ember you want to use. One of the main backbones of Ember.js is the Ember Data library, which cooperates closely with Ember models, which you can read about [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/). If you decide not to use Ember Data (which I think most wouldn't recommend but is ultimately up to you) you can just populate your models manually, using API requests made with ajax and setting model properties with their responses data.

If you want to use Ember Data for your API requests, you will need to use an API adapter, which will let you use Ember Data methods to query your API for your models , so that you can write code like `store.findRecord('book', bookId);`, where the API calls are handled automatically by the adapter, and caching / storage is dealt with by Ember Data.

You can read about adapters [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/), and should probably just read the whole section on models to learn more about how they work whether and how you want to use Ember Data in your application.

Comment: Ember Data is not only cooperating closely with Models but bringing it's one Model class `DS.Model`. Ember core does not have a Model class as it does not have an ORM. It's totally fine to build an ember application without Models - but I agree that it's not the best idea for most use cases as you have to reinvent the wheel if you are getting more complex tasks than fetching data in `model` hook of a Route.

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't worry about Ember Data if all you're trying to do is make a `POST` request.

I would just rely on the "normal" browser APIs for making network requests. These days, the easiest way to go is using the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) API.

There's a handy Ember addon called `ember-fetch` that will wrap the Browser-provided function and make it play a little nicer with Ember. You can install it by doing

```
ember install ember-fetch
```

Once you have it installed, you can import the `fetch` function from that module and go to town!

A quick example of using this in an Ember component might look something like this Twiddle I whipped up.

https://ember-twiddle.com/2511bf1b2409da2b7ff33d88fb12552e?openFiles=components.some-submitting-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.some-submitting-component.hbs

Note that, while the code is correct, the `POST` will fail because it doesn't actually go to a real API.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax for REST api call

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"[postURL]",
        async:false,
        data:{[data you need to send]}
        success:function(data){
             console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Here is the sample code. Try this
https://ember-twiddle.com/e4ebddc075da81462224152fc770b983?openFiles=components.form-submit.js%2C